# Invalid procedure call or argument error in macro

Tags: vba

I have created .bat file which I like to run in vba Excel, I have a code(code1) to run the .bat file. It works fine when it alone but if run with object code(I given in below code2) it throws error.

```
 sub batfile() '-->code1
 Dim a As Integer
 ChDir ("C:\Users\tshiv\source")
 a = Shell("test.bat", vbNormalFocus)
 end sub

 sub creatbatfile()
 Dim FSO As Object
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim TextFile As Object
 Dim strtext As String
 strtext = "C:\Users\tshiv\source\test.bat"
 Set TextFile = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\tshiv\source\test.bat")
 TextFile.Write "netsh wlan show profile | clip"
 Dim a As Integer
 ChDir ("C:\Users\tshiv\source")
 a = Shell("test.bat", vbNormalFocus) --> shows Invalid procedure call or argument error
 end sub
```

kindly verify

Answer (score 0):

We can use measures based on EXCEPT and INTERSECT. First, we need to know what is year in the current row. We create a variable, then virtual tablevariable with SupplierID for this and prev year. Next, we can compare both.

```
SubInCurrAndPrevYear = 
var __currYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date      ]))
var __PrevYear = __currYear -1
var __SupPREV = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __PrevYear)
var __SupCurr = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __currYear)

return
    COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(__SupCurr,__SupPREV))


SubLostThisYear = 
var __currYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date      ]))
var __PrevYear = __currYear -1
var __SupPREV = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __PrevYear)
var __SupCurr = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __currYear)

return
    COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(__SupPREV, __SupCurr))

SubNewThisYear = 
var __currYear = YEAR(SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date      ]))
var __PrevYear = __currYear -1
var __SupPREV = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __PrevYear)
var __SupCurr = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Sheet1[ SupplierID ]), year(Sheet1[Date      ]) = __currYear)

return
    COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(__SupCurr,__SupPREV))
```